# Getting value from a property according to some parameters

Tags: c#

Im curious if my approach is correct in this case:

I would like to get two DateTimes from a public property, but one of the dates i want them only if a user has purchase a feature or if he has not activate a switch, otherwise i want to get the same DateTime twice.

More specifically, the way im getting the values now is this:

```
public class MainApplication : Application
{
public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
public DateTime DateTo { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}

AnotherClass
{
            SearchButton.Click += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                await SearchFoNumbersAsync(ApplicationState.DateFrom, ApplicationState.DateTo, DailySearchSwitch.Checked, SeperateCheckBox.Checked, ShowListsCheckBox.Checked).ConfigureAwait(false);
            };
            private async Task SearchFoNumbersAsync(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo, bool isDailySearchEnabled, bool seperateSearch, bool showDrawTime)
            {
                ((MainActivity)Activity).DisplayLoadingMessage(true, GetString(Resource.String.Common_SearchTitle), GetString(Resource.String.Common_SearchMessage));

                if (isDailySearchEnabled || !PurchaseFunctions.HasPurchasedDateRangeSelection())
                    dateTo = dateFrom;
...
            }
}
```

So i want to get **DateTo** only
**if (isDailySearchEnabled || !PurchaseFunctions.HasPurchasedDateRangeSelection())**, otherwise i want to get the **DateFrom** value in the place of **DateTo**

Im sure this approach is not correct so im thinking i should get the **DateTo** this way:

```
public class MainApplication : Application
{
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    private DateTime DateTo { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public DateTime GetDateTo(bool isDailySearchEnabled)
    {
        if (isDailySearchEnabled || !PurchaseFunctions.HasPurchasedDateRangeSelection())
             return DateFrom;
        else
             return DateTo;
    }

    public void SetDateTo(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        DateTo = dateTime;
    }
}
```

Is my new approach a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the direction is correct but the class API is inconsistent for now. `DateFrom` is available, `DateTo` is not.

As for me, the following way looks more consistent.

```csharp
public class MainApplication : Application
{
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public DateTime GetSearchDate(bool isDailySearchEnabled)
        => isDailySearchEnabled || !PurchaseFunctions.HasPurchasedDateRangeSelection() ? DateFrom : DateTo;
}
```